# GRUB can't find my Windows install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mount

I just added a new SSD to my laptop. I installed Windows on it, and booted into Windows, and all is good.

Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my second SSD, rebooted, and no GRUB menu appeared! I installed some updates, rebooted again, then did `sudo update-grub`, which gave me this:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Still no Windows found! I can see the drive with Windows installed, because it is auto-mounted when I log in. WTH is going on and how do I fix it?

Here is the output of `lsblk`. My Windows install is on `sdc`, and the drive mounted to `/windows` is a big NTFS drive for media.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 111.8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 668.9G  0 part /windows
└─sdb2   8:18   0  29.8G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 223.6G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 223.6G  0 part /media/chris/920E78CD0E78ABBB
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: When you installed Windows did you have both drives connected. And Windows is in sdb1, but if sda was default boot, then the normally hidden 100MB Windows boot partition would be on sda. And your install of Ubuntu to sda, would overwrite that Windows boot partition. Windows does not have to have the separate boot partition, but you now have to run Windows repairs to add bootmgr & BCD to sdb1. Make sure boot flag is on sdb1 and BIOS set to boot sdb before trying repairs. If not post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: @oldfred
So you are saying that i need to install the windows boot manager to sdc?

`/windows` is **not** my windows install, which I mentioned. Also, `sda` is the first hard drive in the boot sequence, which you correctly guessed.

I did have all drives attached when both windows and ubuntu were installed.

So you are saying that the windows installer installed the windows boot manager on the first drive in the boot sequence? How do I make it install it's boot manager on a different drive?

Comment: That was a guess based on Windows normally installing to two partitions, Boot and main install. You can repair main install to include boot but have to use Windows repairs which I do not know details. Better to check with a Windows site. To confirm that you do not have bootmgr nor BCD you can run this which shows necessary boot files.  Post link it gives: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info It cannot fix most Windows issues as you need your Windows repairCD or flash drive and the repair console. My last Windows was XP so not sure of details now.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work you can manually boot windows by going in bios and moving whichever harddisk you want to boot to the top of the list.

Its annoying but it'll work.